# Dynamic created array length shows zero

Tags: jquery, json

I know this questions is asked several times but most answers are in plain javascript.

I have a function that creates an array with product data. That array is used in an other function to get new data via JSON.

```
$(function(){
  var product_info = []
  $('.prod').each(function(){
    product_info.push({ 
      id: $(this).data('pid'), amt: $(this).data('qty'), vid: $(this).data('vid'), url: 'some-url/'+$(this).data('pid')+'?secret=secret&quantity='+$(this).data('qty')
    })
  });
  getId(product_info)
});

function getId(product){
  var matched_variant = []
  $.each(product, function(index, item) {
    var vid = item['vid']
    $.getJSON(item['url'], function(data){
      $.each(data.variants, function(i, variant){
         if(variant.id == vid){
           matched_variant.push({
                id: variant.id, dt: Number(variant.deliveryTimeInDays), dtt: variant.deliveryTime, co: variant.cutOffTime, sid: variant.supplier_id 
          })
         }
      });
    }); 
  });
  console.log(matched_variant.length, matched_variant)
}
```

When I do a console.log `matched_variant.length` it always shows `0`. But there are elemets in it as seen below (copied from console.log)

```
[
  {
    "id": 79380296,
    "dt": 3,
    "dtt": "in three days",
    "co": "15:00",
    "sid": 5
  },
  {
    "id": 79380299,
    "dt": 1,
    "dtt": "same day",
    "co": "17:00",
    "sid": 5
  }
]
```

Why does the length always equals zero then? 
I've read that this could have something to do with `asynchronyous`(??). But what should be done then? Creating some sort of success function?

Any help greatly appreciated!

**Updated with data response**

```
 {
  "id": 41853029,
  "variants": {
    "79380290": {
      "id": 79380290,
      "supplier_id": 5,
      "on_stock": "no",
      "levelLocal": 0,
      "levelSupplier": 0,
      "deliveryTime": "niet leverbaar",
      "cutOffTime": "15:00",
      "deliveryTimeInDays": -1
    },
    "79380293": {
      "id": 79380293,
      "supplier_id": 5,
      "on_stock": "no",
      "levelLocal": 0,
      "levelSupplier": 0,
      "deliveryTime": "niet leverbaar",
      "cutOffTime": "15:00",
      "deliveryTimeInDays": -1
    },
    "79380296": {
      "id": 79380296,
      "supplier_id": 5,
      "on_stock": "supplier",
      "levelLocal": 1,
      "levelSupplier": 250,
      "deliveryTime": "Voor 15:00 uur besteld, over 3 werkdagen in huis",
      "cutOffTime": "15:00",
      "deliveryTimeInDays": 3
    },
    "79380299": {
      "id": 79380299,
      "supplier_id": 5,
      "on_stock": "supplier",
      "levelLocal": 2,
      "levelSupplier": 250,
      "deliveryTime": "Voor 15:00 uur besteld, over 3 werkdagen in huis",
      "cutOffTime": "15:00",
      "deliveryTimeInDays": 3
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: [`$.getJSON()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/) is asynchonous... So the `.each()` lopp ends and the `console.log()` is executed before any result is fetched...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes...`$.getJSON()` is asynchronous ... and also returns a Promise

When you have multiple requests that are all needed to populate one final array start with an array of promises and use `Promise.all()` to process the results of all those promises

Something along the lines of:

```
// usage
getAllItems().then(function(res){
   // all requests have completed and res is combined results
   console.log(res);
}).catch(function(){
   console.log("One of the requests failed")
});



function getItemData(item) {
  // return single item request promise
  return $.getJSON(item.url).then(function(data) {
    // filter and map the response data required
    return Object.values(data.variants).filter(function(variant) {
      variant.id == item.vid
    }).map(function(variant) {
      return {
        id: variant.id,
        dt: Number(variant.deliveryTimeInDays),
        dtt: variant.deliveryTime,
        co: variant.cutOffTime,
        sid: variant.supplier_id
      }    
    });
  });

}

function getAllItems() {    
  var promiseArray = $('.prod').map(function() {    
    var item = {
      id: $(this).data('pid'),
      amt: $(this).data('qty'),
      vid: $(this).data('vid'),
      url: 'some-url/' + $(this).data('pid') + '?secret=secret&quantity=' + $(this).data('qty')
    };
    // return promise from getItemData()
    return getItemData(item);

  }).get();

  // return promise
  return Promise.all(promiseArray).then(function(res){
     // flatten all the sub arrays produced in getItemData()
     return [].concat.apply([], res)
  })

}
```

Comment: Ohh man that is a better approach!! One question... I get an error saying `Typerror: data.filter is not a function`. I'm still learning, but is this because of `variant` not excisting?

Comment: Would mean that `data` isn't an array since `filter` is an array method. I see it...I missed the `variants` property of your response. Change that to `data.variants.filter`. Assumes that data.variants will ALWAYS be an array also

Comment: Ok I don't fully understand I guess :( I've added the data response in my question. This is not an array indeed. But that can be converted with `makearray` I guess. However can it be that there must be some sort `foreach` function to iterata over the various variants inside `variants`?

Comment: Yes try filtering `Object.values(data.variants)` which returns array

Comment: Ok `Object.values(data.variants)` seems to work. I'm trying to understand what is happening with your code and what does what. Doing now `console.log(res)` is an empty array. Any idea why?

Comment: see what's in the promise.all `res`

Comment: When i do `console.log(promiseArray)` I get 2 objects with state, always, then etc... When I do console.log `res` I get an array with two empty arrays in it. The 2 arrays are good (selected two products), but offcourse the data is missing. In the meantime I've read about promises but I don't get the hang of it :)